# Drupal services authentication not sending useful error to device

Tags: angular, cordova, drupal

I have built a Cordova app using Ionic, which communicates with a Drupal backed using Basic Authentication using angular's $http service. When entering the incorrect password in a desktop browser I get a useful error message. When connecting from the device however, there is just a timeout.

My CORS settings for the browser are:
api/*|http://localhost:8100|GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS|Authentication, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token|true

Am I missing a piece of the puzzle? Do I need a CORS entry for the device, and what should this be?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that for 401 errors Drupal returns (correctly) a WWW-Authenticate header, which webviews on devices (and therefore any cordova app) do not work well with. The Answer was to remove the header from the server, which thankfully I was able to do.